# Is there any programming language/framework to be used to develop a mobile app for Android,Apple-ios,Windows Mobile OS

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7

Maybe some might find this, a hypothetical question.
I have recently started development of mobile application development for Android. Currently studying the basics of it. It got me thinking, if one has to develop an application  which is portable and executes just fine on each of OS/platforms namely - Android, Apple -IOS,Windows Phone-7, then

1] What programming language,SDK/framework and tools should one be using? Is there any one thing or one has to pick and match different code frameworks for different tasks in app. development?

2] Would this be a realistic scenario at all if not already?

3] What tools(compilers/build tools, debugging tools, code editors) are available for such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What programming language,SDK/framework and tools should one be using?

JavaScript, HTML5, and [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

> Would this be a realistic scenario at all if not already?

If you can live within the confines of what JavaScript, HTML5, and PhoneGap give you, it is perfectly realistic.

(BTW, if you are more into gaming, that's not my area of expertise, but Unity 3D and other game engines might work -- there's definitely some that work between iOS and Android, but I don't know about Windows Phone 7)

> What tools(compilers/build tools, debugging tools, code editors) are available for such task?

Any text editor, PhoneGap/Build, etc.

Answer (score 2):

While I have not tried it, there is a project, Mono Touch, that allegedly allows cross-platform development.  The argument that I've seen against this kind of development, however (and I agree with it), is that users of each platform are used to how that platform's UI works.  There are ways that the UI acts that are "normal" for a platform, that are not the same for the other platforms.  So if you develop on one, and use something like Mono Touch to make it work on other platforms, your app might work, but the UX would suffer, because on two of the platforms, the UI would not work in the same way that users of that platform are accustomed.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Check this one out.. http://xamarin.com/ use c#/.net and it will "compile" (with minimal changes) to both ios and android, with most of the features of c# available.

Haven't tried it but they have a nice trial, and I'm seriously thinking to move into it. You'll need a Mac for iOS anyway. For WP7/Android, you can use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

According to my opinion, although there are some solutions to produce cross-platform applications, like phonegap, mono touch etc., none of them has very qualified. In order to produce a great mobile app family, a significant effort is needed to write all the apps using different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any solution that I really like, but there is an programming languangue called Revolution Live Code that you can deploy your program to Windows, Mac, IOs and Android (http://www.runrev.com). I programmed with this platform and it's a bit limited.
By the way it's an interesting programming language if you like Smalltalk.